# Can't load page in Spring Boot using th:object

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

It contains a line error: "An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates//register.html]")".
I can't open register html page to add new object into db. why?

```html
<form th:action="@{/register-user}" th:object="user" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="pswd">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-check">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
    </form>
```

My controller

```java
@RequestMapping(path="/register-user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerNewUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user){
        userService.register(user);
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
```

Comment: What error you are getting can you share that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "user" is a model attribute, hence, to access it (and use it as the `th:object`) you gotta use the `${...}` syntax. The result would look like this:

```
<form th:action="@{/register-user}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
```